# How to do value counts with groupby in a numpy array pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'s': ['a','b','a','a'], 'versions':[['1','2'],'2',['1','2'],'2']})
```

I would like to `value_counts()` he columns `versions` by group `s`

I have tried

```
foo.groupby('s')['versions'].value_counts()
```

but i get an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert lists/arrays to hashable tuples, but because there are also strings need `if-else` statement for avoid split strings `100` to tuple `(1,0,0)`:

```
foo['versions'] = foo['versions'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else (x,))
print (foo)
   s versions
0  a   (1, 2)
1  b     (2,)
2  a   (1, 2)
3  a     (2,)

s = foo.groupby('s')['versions'].value_counts()
print (s)
s  versions
a  (1, 2)      2
   (2,)        1
b  (2,)        1
Name: versions, dtype: int64
```